# Rules: after saving new content + after updating existing content both triggered on node create

Tags: rules

I have two rules -

1. Triggers - after new content is saved
2. Triggers - after updating existing content

**Problem**

- When I create a new node both rules are getting triggered together.

**Probable Cause**

- I have an image field in my content type. Something that I found - "...Drupal re-saves the node just because it has a file attached to it...". Refer - http://drupal.org/node/1281960#comment-5065932

However, there must be some solution to this. Please any suggestions, workarounds, solutions...anybody?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a condition in both rules to check whether the `$node->created` and `$node->changed` timestamps are same.

For a newly created node `$node->created` and `$node->changed` time will be same, while for an updated node both will be having different timestamps.

You probably need to add an **Execute custom PHP code** in rule condition to do this.

Comment: You can also use $node->new flag also...

Comment: Checking with $node->created and $node->changed worked smooth..awesome!...@DineshKumar a description in tokens under rules says - $node->is_new : 'Whether the node is new and not saved to the database yet.', I suppose its not what I want here. But thanks anyway for trying to help.