# Rules: after saving new content and after updating existing content both triggered on node create

Tags: nodes, rules, updating

I define two rules that should send an email once new node has been created. And second rule once user updated his content.

The problem I am having here is that both rules trigger in one time when your create a new node.

I found the same issue has been asked in anther question but not very clear and i am not able to understand [enter link description here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58060/rules-after-saving-new-content-after-updating-existing-content-both-triggered)

But I am not able to understand.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy to accomplish, you have a few attributes of the node to compare and check in order to decide which trigger to be true/false.

Method 1: 
Put the following PHP code into your both conditions (create & update) by selecting execute PHP code

CREATE

```
if($node->created == $node->changed) { 
   return true; 
} else { 
   return false; 
}
```

UPDATE

```
if($node->created != $node->changed) {
    return true; 
} else { 
   return false; 
}
```

Method 2:

UPDATE:

```
if($node->is_new) {
     return false; 
} else {
     return true; 
}
```

OR

```
if(!empty($node->nid)) {
    return true; 
} else {
    return false; 
}
```

I have not checked the Method 2 but, method 1 is easier and should definitely work out for you.

Don't forget to Accept this answer solve your problem.

Cheers.

Raf.